# How to pass array objects or store them in reducer using interface and how does filter works on it?

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux-reducers

I had a problem when storing an object array in state using reducers. I had this code this below:

This is my interface:

```
interface fontStyle {
     fontSize: number;
     fontData: FontFamily[];
}

interface FontFamily {
     family: string;
}
```

This is where it loaded and the reducers is just storing the state.

```
const {state, dispatch} = fontReducer();
const font: fontData[] = []
for (let font in data.items) {
    font.push({ family: font.family,})
}
dispatch({type: 'fontStyle', action: font})
```

Then once I tried to do an unordered list with search

```
<ul>
    {state.fontData.filter((item) => item.family.toLowerCase().includes(search)).map(font => (
         <li key={font.family}} onClick={selectFont}> {font.family} </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

The filter won't recognize fontData and had an error that this is undefined => `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`

Here is the reducer -

```js
const fontReducerHandler = () => { 
    switch (action.type) { 
        case "fontStyle": 
            return { ...state, fontData: action.fontData }
    }
}

const initialState: fontStyle { 
    fontSize: 0, 
    fontData: [], 
}

export const fontReducer = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fontReducerHandler, initialState);
    return { state, dispatch }
}
```

Comment: Correction in const font - it should FontFamily[] = [] instead of fontData

Comment: `state.fontData` must be `undefined` then - can you show us the reducer, and the selector that you're using to get `state.fontData`?

Comment: There is state.fontData.

const fontReducerHandler = () => {
     switch(action.type) {
          case "fontStyle" :
               return {...state, fontData: action.fontData}
     } 
}

const initialState: fontStyle {
      fontSize: 0,
      fontData: [],
}
export const fontReducer = () => {
     const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fontReducerHandler , initialState);
     return {state, dispatch}
}

Comment: It looks like there's no `action.fontData` - in the reducer, before the `switch`, try doing a `console.log(action)`

Comment: Actually, I tried it there is action.fontData,  sorry if I missed the type:
type Action = {  type: "fontStyle" fontData: FontFamily[] }

Comment: I always got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: But When I console.log the state, data is present.

Comment: But your dispatch says - `dispatch({type: 'fontStyle', action: font})` (instead of `{ type: 'fontStyle', fontData: font }`) which means the action would have a `type` and and an `action` property but no `fontData` property... so that means `state.fontData` would become undefined when it's run through the reducer, which would then cause the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Seems you are accessing the action payload incorrectly. You dispatch

```
const font: fontData[] = [];
for (let font in data.items) {
  font.push({ family: font.family,});
}
dispatch({ type: 'fontStyle', action: font })
```

Where the `action` ***is*** the fontData array, but in the reducer you access `action.fontData` which is undefined.

```
const fontReducerHandler = () => { 
  switch (action.type) { 
    case "fontStyle": 
        return { ...state, fontData: action.fontData } // action.fontData undefined!!
  }
}
```

## Solution

Access the action payload properly.

```
const fontReducerHandler = () => { 
  switch (action.type) { 
    case "fontStyle": 
        return { ...state, fontData: action.action }
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can form the action object correctly to match how it's accessed in the reducer function.

```
const font: fontData[] = [];
for (let font in data.items) {
  font.push({ family: font.family,});
}
dispatch({ type: 'fontStyle', fontData: font });
```

Now `action.fontData` is defined.